# Apache server running Passenger can't display Rails app

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, indexes, directory-listing

I have a project that was pulled from github into my /home partition, and made symbolic links to the /var partition as per convention.

How it looks :

**/home/vagrant/github/whois-dreyfus** --> repo of the actual project

**/var/www/whois-dreyfus** --> symlink i am using for Apache

I have Apache 2.2.22 and Passenger 4.0.56 installed inside a vagrant box and running on a distant server. The problem is that when accessing to it through my private network, the whole repository is displayed instead of the index. This means if say i had **192.100.93.88** point to the *index page of apache*, **192.100.93.88/whois-dreyfus** on the other hand displays the repo and not the index page of the project.

Furthermore, i have tested this project on a local machine using Webrick so i am confident the issue is coming from the webserver.

So, how can i run my rails app ?

The issue is similar to this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/304897/rails-program-is-not-being-run-on-apache-passenger-only-directory-listing) but i couldn't find any answer wich leads to my question.

Here are my config files :

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
# Load the passenger module for Apache

   LoadModule passenger_module /opt/passenger/passenger-4.0.56/buildout/apache2$
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /opt/passenger/passenger-4.0.56
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/github/whois-dreyfus/public
         RailsBaseURI /whois-dreyfus
      <Directory /home/vagrant/github/whois-dreyfus/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted

        PassengerEnabled on
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
192.168.100.88  app     app     whois-dreyfus
```

Please tell me if something remains unclear and/or needs a better explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you still have the default site enabled in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, which has a DocumentRoot of /var/www, and that's what is serving the content to you currently.